# Javascript (Overlay Menu) Close Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my site I have a number of overlays with two different transitions. One for the Menu Overlay which fades in on top and one for Page Overlays which pushes the main content horizontally.

When a user clicks on the menu hamburger button an overlay opens. Currently clicking on an a menu option link creates a transition that should only be applied when a user opens a Page Overlay. The transition happens when the class .wrap-open is added to .wrap pushing the main content horizontally. This creates an adverse effect of blanking the screen white but really .wrap-open should be removed from .wrap.

**JS Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/te0s2e86/4/

Clicking on Link 1 and Link 2 works great but clicking on a menu link once opened kills the experience.

**My question: How do I fix this so I retain the transition effect for Page Overlays but remove it when the Menu is closed by clicking on a menu option?**

**JS Code:**

```
(function() {
  var triggerBtn = $('.trigger-overlay'), 
      closeBtn = $('.overlay-close'), 
      wrap = $('.wrap'), 
      closeMenu = $('.menu-close'), 
      transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
         },
      transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')],
      support = { transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions
         };

  function toggleOverlay() {
    var data_href = $(this).attr('data-href'), is_menu = ( data_href == "menu" ), overlay = $('#'+ data_href );
        if(!is_menu) $('.wrap-open,.close,.zap').removeClass('wrap-open').removeClass('close').removeClass('zap');

    // If overlay is open
    if (overlay.hasClass('zap')) {

      overlay.removeClass('zap').addClass('close');
      wrap.removeClass('wrap-open');

      var onEndTransitionFn = function(ev) {
        if (support.transitions) {
          if (ev.propertyName !== 'visibility') return;
          this.removeEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
        }
        overlay.removeClass('close');
      };

      if (support.transitions) {
        overlay.get(0).addEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
      } else {
        onEndTransitionFn();
      }
    }

    // If overlay isn't closed
    else if (!overlay.hasClass('close')) {

      if(!is_menu){wrap.addClass('wrap-open');}
      overlay.addClass('zap');
    }
    // If overlay is closed
    else if (overlay.hasClass('close')) {
      if(!is_menu){wrap.addClass('wrap-open');}
      overlay.addClass('zap');

    }
  }


  triggerBtn.each( function(idx){ $(this).click( toggleOverlay ); } );
  closeMenu.each( function(idx){ $(this).click( toggleOverlay ); } );
  closeBtn.each( function(idx){ $(this).click( function(evt){ $(this.parentNode).removeClass('zap'); $('.wrap').removeClass('wrap-open'); } ) } );


})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.overlayshow {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  transition: height 0.5s, padding-top 0.5s;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;  
}
```

```css
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('overlayshow');
})
```

```html
<nav>
  <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner">button</span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <div class="overlay">
    menu list goes hee 
  </div>
</nav>
```